# wireless sensor baud rate calculation

Tags: rf, wireless, bandwidth, baudrate, bit-rate

I need to calculate baud rate of wireless sensor which operates on 433.92Mhz and uses OOK modulation.
Signal wave form and packet structure are known. 
Packet = 36bit (44.7ms), each bit consists of 2 impulses with different duration  (bit 0 - LOW & 2HIGH, bit 1 - 2LOW & HIGH)

So the question is how to calculate baud rate for this sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Baud rate is the number of symbols per second.

You have 36 bits, each bit is made up of 3 symbols (011 or 001), so there are 108 symbols.

One packet takes 44.7ms, so the symbol rate is \$\frac{108}{0.0447}\$ = 2416.1 symbols per second.

As each bit is 3 symbols you also know that it equates to \$\frac{2416.1}{3}\$ = 805.4 bits per second.  You can confirm that as \$\frac{36}{0.0447} = 805.4\$ bits per second.